# How to execute for loop for all test cases using the base class @BeforeMethod in Junit

Tags: java, testing, java-8, automation, junit4

Let's say I have a `Base` class:

```
Class BaseClass{

  @BeforeClass
  public static void testBefore(){
     //some work done here

  }
}

Class TestClass extends BaseClass{

  @Test
  public void testmethod1(){
     for (String x: listOfX){
      // some other assertions here here
     }
  }

  @Test
  public void testmethod2(){
     for (String x: listOfX){
      // some other assertions here here
     }
  }
}
```

My question is what would be a good way to avoid these for loops within each `testmethod()`. Is there a way to move this for loop in `@BeforeMethod` etc so that `testMethod()` executes once per `X`. Your suggestions are very much appreciated and thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't. This is just a poor man's [parameterized test](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5)

Answer (score 0):

As Michael mentioned, this is not a good idea and you should use parameterized tests instead. Running for loops in tests isn't terrible, but you definitely don't want to create a new test for every value. The overhead of starting a new test each time will slow you down much more than duplicating the for loops.